# Segmentation Fault while comparing strings

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

In my program, there is a part where i need to sort an array of struct.
Everything goes nice until the end i think.
For some entries everything is nice and works until some entries at the end of the array.
There it throws a segmentation fault and i don't know why.

```
struct overview_table{
    string o_timestamp;
    string n_timestamp;
    string dbID;
};


sort(overview.begin(),overview.end(),compareStrings);

static bool compareStrings(const overview_table &a_timestamp, const overview_table &b_timestamp){
    cout << "744" << endl;
    if ( a_timestamp.n_timestamp.compare(b_timestamp.n_timestamp) <= 0){
        cout << "746" << endl;
        return true;
    } else {
        cout << "749" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

For information: the output was only to check where the segmentation fault is thrown. And it is between 744 and 746 and how i think at the end of the array. But i don't know why

Comment: We lack half the code to be able to help you.

Comment: Time to fire up the debugger.

Comment: Try `a_timestamp.n_timestamp.compare(b_timestamp.n_timestamp) < 0` (or `a_timestamp.n_timestamp < b_timestamp.n_timestamp`). `std::sort` requires a strict weak order. `<=` is not irreflexive, and so is not a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compare function shall satisfy the principle of weak ordering.

Change the function the following way

```
static bool compareStrings( const overview_table &a_timestamp, 
                            const overview_table &b_timestamp )
{
   return a_timestamp.n_timestamp < b_timestamp.n_timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, to sort 2 structs you have to compare the whole struct, not only a field. And you're comparing only the *n_timestamp* field. Second, you don't put <= in the comparison but just < or >.

This is an example of an operator overload:

```
bool operator<(const overview_table &a, const overview_table &b)
{
    if ( a.n_timestamp.compare(b.n_timestamp) < 0) {return true;}
    if ( a.n_timestamp.compare(b.n_timestamp) > 0) {return false;}
    if ( a.o_timestamp.compare(b.o_timestamp) < 0) {return true;}
    if ( a.o_timestamp.compare(b.o_timestamp) > 0) {return false;}
    return a.dbID.compare(b.dbID);
}
```

hope this helps. Pleas ask if I was not clear!

Comment: Of course you can write whatever you need inside the return brackets, and adjust the order of the comparisons according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A little more source would be nice...

But first of all: compare should return 0 in case of equality, so your

```
if ( a_timestamp.n_timestamp.compare(b_timestamp.n_timestamp) <= 0)
```

doesn't make any sense... Otherwise (if it's intended) your function's name is misleading.

To figure out, where your segmentation fault comes from, we need to see more sourcecode, but Segmentation faults indicate, that you are trying to acces nestet values from a null pointer, so in your case it seems, that one of your compared structs was never created...
Which could and should be checked by a `if (null == x)` return false; or something like that